# Shell script to convert key-value pairs to CSV

Tags: bash, shell, csv, export-to-csv, keyvaluepair

I have got a file consisting of multiple key-value pairs and each entry for a set of key-value pairs is separated by a blank line. The file looks something like this:

```
Name = Jhon
Age = 27
Street = LA Road
Occupation = Service
Gender = M

Name = Anindya
Gender = M
Street = GNB Road
Occupation = Consultant
Age = 26
Phone = 0987654321

Age = 55
Gender = F
Street = Jodhpur Road
Name = Gopa

Gender = M
Name = Ashok
Occupation = Service
Phone = 1234567890
```

And I want the following output from the code after processing the file:

```
Name,Age,Gender,Street,Occupation,Phone
Jhon,27,M,LA Road,Service,
Anindya,26,M,GNB Road,Consultant,0987654321
Gopa,55,F,Jodhpur Park,,
Ashok,,M,,Service,1234567890
```

I have tried using awk, but the arrangements of the keys are not consistent and as a result I do not get a desired output.

I need a Bash script that can give me the above mentioned output.

Comment: Try look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147816/convert-key-value-blocks-to-csv

Comment: @AvihooMamka. Hmmm.... no. The accepted solution for the link you posted here above doesn't work in this case because the order of the rows in each group is not fixed.

Comment: @AvihooMamka That is for consistent data.

Comment: First, try yourself write the script, then post here your question about your script. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

Store the values in an associative array (bash version 4 needed).

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

columns=(Name Age Gender Street Occupation Phone)

declare -A record header
for c in "${columns[@]}" ; do
    record[$c]=$c
    header[$c]=1
done

output () {
    for ((i=0; i<${#columns[@]}; i++ )) ; do
        k=${columns[i]}
        printf %s "${record[$k]:-}"
        if (( i+1 != ${#columns[@]} )) ; then
            printf ,
        fi
    done
    echo
}

# Print the header.
output
record=()

while read key eq value ; do
    if [[ ! $key ]] ; then
        output
        record=()

    elif [[ $eq != = ]] ; then
        echo Invalid line "$key $eq $value" >&2
        exit 1

    elif [[ ! ${header[$key]:-} ]] ; then
        echo Invalid key "'$key'" >&2
        exit 1

    else 
        record[$key]=$value
    fi
done

# Don't forget the last line!
output
```

Comment: Note associative array are only available in bash 4+

Comment: Thanks @Choroba!!! The script is working however the spaces are removed form the values.

Comment: @Andy: Sorry, double quotes missing in `printf`. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Not a problem for awk:

```
awk -F " = " -v OFS="," '
    BEGIN { print "Name", "Age", "Gender", "Street", "Occupation", "Phone" }
    function printline() {
        print data["Name"], data["Age"], data["Gender"], data["Street"], data["Occupation"], data["Phone"]
    }
    {data[$1] = $2}
    NF == 0 {printline(); delete data}
    END {printline()}
'
```

outputs

```
Name,Age,Gender,Street,Occupation,Phone
Jhon,27,M,LA,Service,
Anindya,26,M,GNB,Consultant,0987654321
Gopa,55,F,Jodhpur Road,,
Ashok,,M,,Service,1234567890
```

Comment: Thanks @Glenn, but it seems the values with space gets truncated

Comment: Ah missed that. Answer updated (see https://stackoverflow.com/posts/35460169/revisions for what changed)